# File transfer all images inside a folder to a destination folder via plugin during activation

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

I have a WordPress plugin that, when first activated, sets up some default site settings and creates and adds a few widgets to the site.

I'd like to add some code to my plugin so that during the activation process, it grabs all images inside a folder named "images" (located in the same directory as the plugin script) and transfers them all to the "uploads" folder in WordPress (located at wp-content/uploads).

Can someone provide an example of the code methods required to do this file transfer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If PHP is running as the owner of the files and directories involved, you can simply call [`rename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) with the old location and the new location of each file.

File ownership may be an issue, so your code should be prepared to deal with failures by checking the return value of the function.

Comment: just to clarify, the package that I will be installing via wordpress "plugins > add new > upload > myplugin.zip" will contain the images folder and the images to transfer to the server. They do not already exist on the server. I wasn't clear from your answer that I communicated that well :-)

Comment: WP will extract the zip to a particular location, right?  Rather, your plugin will never actually have to deal with that zip file, will it?  If so, then this answer should still apply, as you'll just be moving the files from one location on the filesystem to another.

Comment: yes WP extracts the [pluginname].zip to the plugins folder of WP. And in the process executes the php scripts in the plugin. I just didn't understand your rename method. I'm familiar with move_uploaded_file, but I havent used rename as a transfer method. So I want to grab the images out of the folder and move them to the wp-content/uploads/ directory.